# Loops for commands in R?

Tags: r, loops

I have a set of commands creating new data frames for a large number of subsets. The command is the same but the only thing that changes are some numbers of the subsets (from 1 to n).

The commands are:

```
a1 <- data[block$block.1$main.inds,]
a2 <- data[block$block.2$main.inds,]
a3 <- data[block$block.3$main.inds,]
.
.
.
a50 <- data[block$block.50$main.inds,]
```

I've tried to automatize this by using the following code but without success:

```
for (i in 1:50) {
        a[i]<- data[block$block.[i]$main.inds,]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better not to create multiple objects in the global env.  In the present situation, we can use `assign`

```
for(i in 1:50) {
    assign(paste0('a', i), data[block[[paste0('block.', i)]]]$main.inds,])
 }
```

---

Or better to store it in a `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(paste0('block.', 1:50), function(bl) data[block[[bl]]]$main.inds,])
names(lst1) <- paste0("a", 1:50)
```

Comment: @TheWalküre Sorry, there was a missing `]`  Updated the code

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I added a "$" that was missing in the code but I get the following error:

```Error: unexpected '[[' in:
"for (i in 1:50) {```

The code is 
```
 for(i in 1:50) {
    assign(paste0('a', i), data[block$[[paste0('block.', i)]]$main.inds,])
 }
```
I removed the double square brackets and that fixes the first error, but I get another one 

```
for (i in 1:49) {
        assign(paste0('albanyvoter15_block',i), albany_voter2015[block_out$paste0('block.',i)$dfA.inds,])
        }

 attempt to apply non-function
```

Comment: @TheWalküre you don't need `block$[[`..  it should be just `block[[paste0(`  The reason I am using `[[` is because we are creating the names dynamically with paste.  If you have a fixed name it could be used with `$`

Comment: @TheWalküre I intentionally omitted the `$` for that dynamic name and it is not a mistake

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I deleted my reply instead of editing several times! Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @TheWalküre If you check the `$` at the end `$main.inds` it is because that value is static.  It can be also be changed to `[[` i.e. `[["main.inds"]]`

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. The code is running and will update you when it's done.

Comment: @TheWalküre ok.  How big is the dataset and can you update your post with the `str(block)` does the 'data' number of rows are the same as the `block` list length

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you so much, @akrun! The data has about 17 million observations. The blocks are pre-partitioned sets according to a variable I selected. They all have various lengths.